# Google PageSpeed showing render-blocking CSS even after moving to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

everyone.

I'm optimizing a website's loading time performance and, for some reason, I can't remove the render-blocking above the fold CSS issue from Google PageSpeed Insights, even after minifying and moving my CSS file down to the bottom of the page.

Can anyone help me?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=praveenchaparala.com&tab=mobile

Thanks!

Comment: Without investigating deeper, what this typically means is that you have CSS selectors in the HTML (above the fold) that cannot be rendered until your `.css` file have been read. To eliminate this warning, you would inline the critical CSS. For example, if the following was above the fold `<p class="my-class">Some stuff</p>`, but `.my-class{}` was in your CSS file, you will get that pagespeed warning. To remove the warning, inline `.my-class{}` into your page. It's called `critical CSS`. My advice? Don't obsess over pagespeed insights. It's just a guide.

Comment: Awesome, Marcus. Thanks for this information!